# angular2 Observable: How to wait asynchronous result and return another asynchronous method

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have to resolve a problem with asynchronous calls. 
Scenario:
`makeReservation` method returns `Observable<SaveResponse>`. When `makeReservation` method is called by a caller should do
1) invoke `send3DRequest` and subscribe to it and wait for `success` Event.
2) in `success` event get necessary details and return another asynchronous method: `return this.reservationHttpService.save(X)`

In my actual implementation I get an error: `Return statement is required for non-void return type`.

```
private makeReservation(reservationDto: ReservationDTO): Observable<SaveResponse>{
  this.reservationHttpService.send3DRequest(reservationDto.threeDQueryDetails)
    .subscribe(
      successResponse => {
        if(successResponse.enrolled === 'Y'){
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;
          reservationDto.acsUrl = successResponse.acsUrl;
          reservationDto.paReq = successResponse.paReq;

          return this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
        }
        else {
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;

          return this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
        }           
      },
      error => { throw new Error(error); });
}
```

--

Then, I tried to make this change *(the problem is described in code)*:

```
private makeReservation(reservationDto: ReservationDTO): Observable<SaveResponse>{

  let saveResponse = new Observable<SaveResponse>(); //added change

  this.reservationHttpService.send3DRequest(reservationDto.threeDQueryDetails)
    .subscribe(
      successResponse => {
        if(successResponse.enrolled === 'Y'){
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;
          reservationDto.acsUrl = successResponse.acsUrl;
          reservationDto.paReq = successResponse.paReq;

          let result = this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
          //HOW TO INSERT the result in saveResponse and notify about change ?
        }
        else {
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;
          let result = this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
          //HOW TO INSERT the result in saveResponse and notify about change ?
        }           
      },
      error => { throw new Error(error); });

     return saveResponse; //added change
}
```

Any idea would are welcome :) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to your method definition :

```
private makeReservation(reservationDto: ReservationDTO): Observable<SaveResponse>
```

You expect `makeReservation` method to return an `Observable` of type `SaveResponse`. But you do not return anything here.

You just start to subscribe on `reservationHttpService.send3DRequest`.

You should rather have :

```
private makeReservation(reservationDto: ReservationDTO): Observable<SaveResponse>{
  return this.reservationHttpService.send3DRequest(reservationDto.threeDQueryDetails)
```

(notice the **return**).

---

So now, if we start from your second example (which is probably the best idea), I'd do something like :

```
private makeReservation(reservationDto: ReservationDTO): Observable<SaveResponse>{
  return this
    .reservationHttpService
    .send3DRequest(reservationDto.threeDQueryDetails)
    .switchMap(response => {
        let result;

        if(successResponse.enrolled === 'Y') {
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;
          reservationDto.acsUrl = successResponse.acsUrl;
          reservationDto.paReq = successResponse.paReq;

          result = this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
        }

        else {
          reservationDto.transRef = successResponse.transactionRef;
          result = this.reservationHttpService.save(reservationDto);
        }

        return Observable.of(result);
      }
    )
    .catch(err => {
      // handle your error here
      return Observable.of({});
    })
}
```

and just don't forget to subscribe on `makeReservation` when you call it :

`this.makeReservation(your_argument).subscribe();`

Comment: Grand merci :) Your hint unblocked the state displayed in my question. Some tech suggestions: Instead of returning `Observable.of(result);` better to return only the `result` which is already an `Observable`. In this way we can avoid creating an additional wrapper. For `Observable.of({});` from `catch(err => )` block can type: `.catch(err => { return Observable.throw(err); })`. Bonne journee!